# Developing a calculator using the command pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

In an attempt to solidify my understanding of the command pattern, I decided to write a  calculator application that utilised it.

After making some progress, I realised that my choice of application may not have been the ideal choice.

[image]

**I have the following components:**

---

**View.xml**

This is the user interface of the calculator, and is equivalent to the “client” in diagram.
This is my view layer.

---

**Controller.cs**

This is the equivalent to the “invoker” in the diagram, this holds the commands, and calls execute on them.
This is my controller layer

---

**Model.cs**

This is the equivalent to the “receiver” on the diagram.

---

**commandOne.cs, comandTwo.cs, commandMinus.cs...... etc**

These are my concrete commands , that define a binding between an action and the model.

---

As well as executing the commands, the controller also mains a queue of commands for the purposes of undo and redo.

In applying the command pattern to a calculator, I realised that execution of the commands is deferred until the entire expression has been created and equals has been pressed. I therefore set about recoding the sequence of button presses in the model layer before realising that I already had a container storing these in the form of the undo/redo queue in the controller.

Therefore, my question is, should I pass my controller/invoker to the model layer when the expression has been completed so that the commands in the queue can be run sequentially to calculate the result.

Or should I persist a similar queue in the model layer for the purposes of evaluating the expression when the equals button has been pressed.

Comment: While this question is not strictly a duplicate, my answer here to a similar question applies to this too: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/257259/which-pattern-is-most-intuitive-for-a-calculator-app/257620#257620

Comment: You should not design an application based on which design pattern you want to use. Your application needs should define what design pattern(s) you should use. You will often run into problems conceptually when you try to fit square pegs into circular holes if you attempt this with drastically different patterns/use cases.

Comment: In MVC, neither your `View` nor your `Controller` should really have any knowledge of your underlying application logic (in this case, your calculator logic).     A `View` is for layout/colours/fonts/etc.   A `Controller` is for Interactivity logic (e.g. enabling/disabling buttons, querying the view for data, or sending data to the view).     As far as MVC is concerned, the `Model` (which may be a slightly misleading term) is a catch-all term meaning *"the rest of your application logic"*.

Comment: @enderland - "You should not design an application based on which design pattern you want to use" - I quite clearly stated that the exercise was to "solidify my understanding of the command pattern", under these circumstances, I think you are wrong.

Comment: @Ben - I agree, therefore passing the controller back is a bad idea, but it does keep the application "dry"

Comment: @whatsisnae - Thanks for the reply, but I don't think your answer applies. The purpose of this exercise is to understand the command pattern.

Comment: It sounds like your model does not change at all until I hit the = key to evaluate the current expression, which would imply the model is effectively one nullable number and nothing else. Is that correct? (If so I think I know what to put in an answer)

Comment: @ixrec - correct, that is the issue I'm facing.

Comment: @dangerousdave: Entirely ignoring/misunderstanding what enderland said doesn't make enderland wrong.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet - Are you suggesting that I should not endeavor to understand the command pattern by trying to actually use it? because the only way I see of doing this, short of stumbling upon a usecase, is contriving a usecase; which is what I have done. Furthermore, in my original question I state "my choice of application may not have been the ideal choice" even so, I don't believe this makes my attempt to learn any less valid.

Comment: @dangerousdave: We're suggesting that you should endeavour to find a problem to solve before trying to solve it. You're going about things entirely backwards. If you don't understand the command pattern, how did you come to the conclusion that you should use it for this project? Clearly you just picked a design pattern for the sake of it, which is not what design patterns are for. If you really want to learn, take our advice!

Comment: @Barry - What a ridiculous corner you have painted yourself into. if the “problem” was to create a calculator application, then your comments would be valid, however, this is a learning exercise. Look in any programming textbook for contrived examples that are used to build knowledge and illustrate concepts. As to why I decided on a calculator as a suitable application for this exercise is not relevant, however it was not selected at random.

Comment: Alright then you know best

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're describing is that the model needs to know the internal state of the controller. This is a symptom of a much bigger problem, namely: Most of the state that belongs in your model is not being stored in your model. The solution here is not to duplicate the controller's state inside the model or pass the controller into the model, but rather to move that state into the model.

A closely related problem is that you're trying to use commands to represent not-yet-performed mathematical operations, when you should really be using them to represent the orders the user is giving your calculator app. It may be counterintuitive, but when the user presses the * button on a calculator, they are not telling the calculator to multiply two numbers, they're actually telling it to add a multiplication symbol to the current expression.

Specifically, **your model should contain a representation of the current expression**, whether that's a single number like "123" or a complicated not-yet-evaluated expression like "3+4*90-8", and **evaluating that expression should be its own command**, separate from the commands to add a * and a 90 and a - and an 8 to the current expression.

For example, if your model is currently "123" and the user presses the * key, the model should be changed to "123*", the view should be told to update itself, and the undo/redo stacks should be given command objects that add and remove a *. Then when the user presses 4, the model should change to "123*4", the view should be told to update itself, and the undo/redo stacks should be given command objects that add/remove a 4. Finally, when the user presses =, the model should be told to evaluate its expression so it changes to "492", the view should be told to update itself, the undo stack should be given a command object that resets the current expression back to "123*4" and the redo stack should be given a command object that evaluates the current expression. This way, there's absolutely no need for the model to ever receive a reference to the controller or the view, and you only need one pair of undo/redo stacks in the controller.

Note that the model doesn't have to be a simple string as I just described. In practice it's often better to represent an expression like this as an AST and give the model a method that converts said AST to a string for the view to display. But for a very simple calculator app a string might be sufficient.

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much Ixrec, you addressed all my issues!